# Web Api call fails now after TLS 1.2 is enforced between our servers

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api

We have a server with a windows service that calls an web api over https in other server (both servers internals) and it was working normal, until they were changed their TLS configuration.

I coded a simple console app for test the call and reproduced the error.
I tested from Firefox from the machine acting as client and is respoding ok (this discard any firewall or port blocks issue)
More strange is I tested from my laptop (win7) and worked ok.

As can be seen in the Exception details fails "`at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(...)`" so seems to be related with changed configuration.
After a lot of research I found some changes done in Registry (not done by me, because I can't but for support area), and change my code adding **ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol** for support Tls.

Any Ideas?

Following almost all instructions on:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/07/12/enable-tls-1-2-protocol-for-reporting-services-with-custom-net-application/

- Development: Visual Studio: 2013
- .Net Framework: version 4.5
- Operation System: Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1

Registry found (made by support personal, these are some of them)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

Sample Console app for testing:

```
public async Task<string> TestApiCall()
{
    const string uri = "https://myserver/api/blahblah";
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "close"); // Keep Alive = false (tested with & without this line)

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls; // tested with almost all combinations since only Tls12
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol &= ~SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3; // Disable SSL3

            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;  // Accept possible invalid certificates (not recomended, only for test), tested without this line too

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);  // <-- Exception thrown here
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
    ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
    ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
    ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at TestHttp.Program.<TestApiCall>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Comment: You don't need like "ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol &= ~SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3; // Disable SSL3" setting SecurityProtocol to valid values would do the job. Disabling protocol is not required.

Comment: Do you see handshake failure status when you trace the call using fiddler?

Comment: Try adding this line to the beginning of your console app to test (before your using statement instead of after): System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls; Unfortunately I'm not somewhere I can test this for you at the moment.

Comment: Could you post a wireshark capture when that exception happens? That would help debugging the tls communication.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes I've tried without that line too

Comment: Hmm... now it becomes matter of trials and errors instead of solution. Can you try by setting SecurityProtocol only to tls1.2 ? Other services on the server are responsing fine? How their clients are making calls? Any chance you can get server logs and see what's exactly happening there?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yeah, as I wrote in the line comment, I tried with all the combinations, including only Tls12

Comment: @Chris Is already in the code and before executing client.GetAsync

Comment: @savageBum We can install or run that tools in production servers/networks, apart that we don't have access to install it.

Comment: as far as i remember, it is something to do with the Certificate validation, when i worked on TLS via WCF net.tcp, i had to install pfx and cer files on the client and server for it to work properly.

on the server you might need to specify <serviceBehaviors> <behavior><serviceCredentials> <serviceCertificate> in the config file.

it worth a shot to look there

Comment: You mentioned testing with Firefox.  Did you try testing with Internet Explorer?  Firefox most likely implements its own cryptography,whereas Internet Explorer uses the same crypto API that .Net does.  This will tell you if your workstation needs to be patched to add support for TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a certificate file send to server. Usually this certificate file is open by the certificate CA ROOT.

```
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    X509Certificate cer = new X509Certificate("F:\\csharp2.cer");  //adding your client certificate.
        httpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cer);
        httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(CallBack(), httpWebRequest);




    private void CallBack()
    {
        AsyncCallback ac = (result) =>
        {

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(result))
            {
                //response
            }
        };
    }


    private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None);
    }
```

Comment: I can't use custom certificate, company uses corporate services to do that

Comment: Can visited your API URL on chrome? if you can then try this, this a way how to export public certificate from chrome : http://www.wikihow.com/Export-Certificate-Public-Key-from-Chrome